# What is the scripture verificiton of the sine-wave based seven vedic gods concept?

Tags: vedas, gods, belief, identification-request, vedic-gods

some of These picture everyone can see flying around the net, tellings about 7 modes of the supreme bhrahman realities.

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

i thinks , There is some of the peculiar answers in several platforms regarding this. An example: [Why aren't the original Rigvedic gods worshipped anymore?](https://www.quora.com/Why-arent-the-original-Rigvedic-gods-worshipped-anymore)

so, what does the scriptures says on this kind of contents? are they true and suported by hindu texts?